# Transfer from one dataframe to another with plyr

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
library(car)
mtcarsSubset <- car::some(mtcars)
mtcarsSubset <- mtcarsSubset[, c("mpg", "drat")]
mtcarsSubset$rows <- rownames(mtcarsSubset)

mtcarsSubset
                    mpg drat               rows
Datsun 710         22.8 3.85         Datsun 710
Duster 360         14.3 3.21         Duster 360
Merc 240D          24.4 3.69          Merc 240D
Merc 280           19.2 3.92           Merc 280
Merc 450SLC        15.2 3.07        Merc 450SLC
Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4 2.93 Cadillac Fleetwood
Toyota Corolla     33.9 4.22     Toyota Corolla
Toyota Corona      21.5 3.70      Toyota Corona
Dodge Challenger   15.5 2.76   Dodge Challenger
Ford Pantera L     15.8 4.22     Ford Pantera L
```

I have a second dataframe that looks like this:

```
mtcars <- mtcars[,c("gear", "carb")]
mtcars$new.variable <- NA
mtcars$rows <- rownames(mtcars)
                    gear carb new.variable                rows
Mazda RX4              4    4           NA           Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag          4    4           NA       Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710             4    1           NA          Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive         3    1           NA      Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout      3    2           NA   Hornet Sportabout
Valiant                3    1           NA             Valiant
Duster 360             3    4           NA          Duster 360
Merc 240D              4    2           NA           Merc 240D
Merc 230               4    2           NA            Merc 230
Merc 280               4    4           NA            Merc 280
Merc 280C              4    4           NA           Merc 280C
Merc 450SE             3    3           NA          Merc 450SE
Merc 450SL             3    3           NA          Merc 450SL
Merc 450SLC            3    3           NA         Merc 450SLC
Cadillac Fleetwood     3    4           NA  Cadillac Fleetwood
Lincoln Continental    3    4           NA Lincoln Continental
Chrysler Imperial      3    4           NA   Chrysler Imperial
Fiat 128               4    1           NA            Fiat 128
Honda Civic            4    2           NA         Honda Civic
Toyota Corolla         4    1           NA      Toyota Corolla
Toyota Corona          3    1           NA       Toyota Corona
Dodge Challenger       3    2           NA    Dodge Challenger
AMC Javelin            3    2           NA         AMC Javelin
Camaro Z28             3    4           NA          Camaro Z28
Pontiac Firebird       3    2           NA    Pontiac Firebird
Fiat X1-9              4    1           NA           Fiat X1-9
Porsche 914-2          5    2           NA       Porsche 914-2
Lotus Europa           5    2           NA        Lotus Europa
Ford Pantera L         5    4           NA      Ford Pantera L
Ferrari Dino           5    6           NA        Ferrari Dino
Maserati Bora          5    8           NA       Maserati Bora
Volvo 142E             4    2           NA          Volvo 142E
```

Where the `row` of `mtcarsSubset` equals `rows` of `mtcars`, I want to transfer `mpg`. I can achieve this with this for loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(mtcarsSubset$rows)) {

  x <- which(mtcars$rows  == mtcarsSubset$rows[i])
  mtcars$new.variable[x] <-  mtcarsSubset$mpg[i]

}

                    gear carb new.variable                rows
Mazda RX4              4    4           NA           Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag          4    4         21.0       Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710             4    1         22.8          Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive         3    1           NA      Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout      3    2           NA   Hornet Sportabout
Valiant                3    1         18.1             Valiant
Duster 360             3    4           NA          Duster 360
Merc 240D              4    2         24.4           Merc 240D
Merc 230               4    2           NA            Merc 230
Merc 280               4    4         19.2            Merc 280
Merc 280C              4    4           NA           Merc 280C
Merc 450SE             3    3           NA          Merc 450SE
Merc 450SL             3    3           NA          Merc 450SL
Merc 450SLC            3    3         15.2         Merc 450SLC
Cadillac Fleetwood     3    4           NA  Cadillac Fleetwood
Lincoln Continental    3    4           NA Lincoln Continental
Chrysler Imperial      3    4           NA   Chrysler Imperial
Fiat 128               4    1         32.4            Fiat 128
Honda Civic            4    2           NA         Honda Civic
Toyota Corolla         4    1           NA      Toyota Corolla
Toyota Corona          3    1           NA       Toyota Corona
Dodge Challenger       3    2           NA    Dodge Challenger
AMC Javelin            3    2         15.2         AMC Javelin
Camaro Z28             3    4         13.3          Camaro Z28
Pontiac Firebird       3    2           NA    Pontiac Firebird
Fiat X1-9              4    1         27.3           Fiat X1-9
Porsche 914-2          5    2           NA       Porsche 914-2
Lotus Europa           5    2           NA        Lotus Europa
Ford Pantera L         5    4           NA      Ford Pantera L
Ferrari Dino           5    6           NA        Ferrari Dino
Maserati Bora          5    8           NA       Maserati Bora
Volvo 142E             4    2           NA          Volvo 142E
```

I'm specifically after a `plyr` solution to accomplish the transfer of `mpg` from `mtcarsSubset` to `mtcars`. I'm envisaging either `ddply()` or `ldply` will be able to achieve this, although I'm not sure how. Is this possible with `plyr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do this specifically with `plyr` in conjunction with `ifelse()`.  You don't need to initialize the variable "new.variable" if you are using `ddply()` with `transform`.

`require(plyr)`

`ddply(mtcars, .(rows), transform, 
            new.variable = ifelse(rows %in% mtcarsSubset$rows, 
                                   mtcarsSubset$mpg[mtcarsSubset$rows == rows], NA) )`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for `merge()`?

`merge(mtcars, mtcarsSubset[ , "new.variable"], by="row.names", all.x=T)`

Comment: I'm specifically after a plyr solution. Plus merge() doesn't work with my real data (I've amended code to it more closely reflects my real data)